# How to disable Windows Media Player controls individually

Tags: c#, winforms, media-player, axwindowsmediaplayer

I'm working on a `C#` application which in I have a `AxWindowsMediaPlayer` control.
I want to disable its controls individually, not all together.
So far I have to use this code which disables all the controls

```
wmpPlayer.Ctlenabled = false;
```

Is there a way to disable for example just `stop` button?

I need to keep the `Duration bar` enabled and I don't want to hide them by `uiMode`.

Comment: i am afraid it is difficult to find a solution because the control does not have a property to disable just one button. but does it make sense to disable stop while user can click pause/next/fast forward?

Comment: @kennyzx The problem is if I use `wmpPlayer.Ctlenabled = false;` it will disables the `Duration bar` as well. But I need to have it enable.

Comment: The automation interface for the look-and-feel of the player was intentionally crippled.  Too much of a hazard to innovation, WMP changed a great deal over the years.  You can't make this work.  Consider creating your own UI and just use WMP for playback.

Answer (score 2):

@Alex Jolig I found the solucion.

1º Select the windows media player and click in property pages (the key in properties), click there.

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ji53b.png)

And select modo, select none in place of mini!!

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtyaF.png)

[And There is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fr2Ol.png)

Welcome!!

Answer (score 0):

I can't found a way to disable controls and make then invisible... but i got the same effect by dragging an image box just over the `Window Media Controls`, so user can't operate and see them...

Answer (score 0):

This should work for not being able to stop:

```
if (axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPaused)
{
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
}
```

Put this on a `Timer` and then `1` on interval. After that just copy the timer and past it 10 times. I don't know if it makes any difference, but works for me as now.

Answer (score 0):

"I can't found a way to disable controls and make then invisible... but i got the same effect by dragging an image box just over the Window Media Controls, so user can't operate and see them..."

Answer to this, since i can't add a comment:
To hide Windows Media Controls:
Click on properties on the player > Controls Layout > None
(This will hide the controls)

To make it invisible:
Put a timer and put enabled = true on properties > right click on the timer and Show Code
Here put in:

If you want to close the player:

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.close();
```

if you want to hide the player, but still play in the background:

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Hide();
```

Click properties on the timer again and choose a interval

This will make Windows Media Player close/hide after a time (interval)